# Where to Include Sugarcrm

Tags: javascript, php, include, sugarcrm, include-path

I have been working on some custom code for a sugar module and am fairly unclear where to put my javascript code to be called in module.

Currently I have put my custom JS in include/javascript/popup_parent_helper.js

This works fine in developer mode but does not work when that is turned off and unfortunately dveloper mode runs SUPER slow

I have done a lot of research and I am getting some conflicting results.

Some tell me that I should include it in:

- /modules/[ModuleName]/

Others say that it should to in:

- /custom/modules/[ModuleName/

  - and some further in adding js as a directory

Please help me clarify proper structure for this and where I need to make my proper include statement

Clarifications:

We are using SugarCrm 6.5x

In this case the JS is only being used for one module.

It is being used in the Quick Create View and the Edit View

Comment: Are you using sugar 7.x?

Comment: What sort of thing does this javascript do? Is it isolated to a particular view (record, list, etc)?

Comment: Clarifications regarding version and details of JS use added

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript should be accessible by any module, you can create a new JSGrouping and pull in your custom js file using the following technique:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/Extension_Framework/JSGroupings/#Creating_New_JSGroupings

It sounds like you want it to be isolated to your custom module, so you should probably extend the view desired. If you are extending the record view, create a new file called record.js at custom/modules/-your_module-/clients/base/views/record/

```
({
extendsFrom: 'RecordView',

initialize: function(options) {
    this._super('initialize', [options]);
    this.doSomething();
},

doSomething: function(){
    console.log("Help you I will");
},

...
```

})

https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/02/10/extending-sugar-7-record-view/

Comment: This method will only work with Sugar 7.x, so won't help you OP. It may help someone else so I will leave it here. The other answer addresses Sugar 6.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced similar issue (JS should be work for edit and quickcreate form) but after making some RnD I achieved it as per following way:

```
\custom\modules\<modulename>\views\view.edit.php

<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.edit.php');

class {moduleName}ViewEdit extends ViewEdit {

      public function __construct() {
        parent::ViewEdit();
        $this->useForSubpanel = true; // this variable specifies that these changes should work for subpanel
       // / $this->useModuleQuickCreateTemplate = true; // quick create template too
    }

    function display(){ ?>
        <?php

                 $jsscript = <<<EOQ
                            <script>
                                    Your JS code
                            </script>
EOQ;

        parent::display();
           echo $jsscript;     //echo the script

    }   

}
?>
```